# Compiling Vim in centos 7 with python

Tags: python-3.x, vim, centos

I am trying to compile vim in Centos 7. The purpose is to use vim as a Python IDE. I found that it has not compiled with python3 from the `vim --version` output. It shows a negative sign before python3.

How can I solve this issue to properly compile vim?

Steps that I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim
yum install python python-devel python36u python36u-devel
yum install tcl-devel perl perl-devel perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS perl-ExtUtils-XSpp perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-Embed cscope gtk3-devel libSM-devel libXt-devel libXpm-devel libappstream-glib libacl-devel gpm-devel
yum install ncurses-devel

CFLAGS+=-fPIC ./configure --with-features=huge \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
    --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
    --enable-python3interp=yes \
    --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config \
    --enable-python3interp=yes \
    --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-tlib=ncurses \
    --enable-perlinterp=yes \
    --enable-luainterp=yes \
    --enable-terminal \
    --enable-cscope \
    --prefix=/usr/local

make && sudo make install

hash -r
```

The output of vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 15 2020 23:16:42)
Included patches: 1-756
Compiled by joel
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl              +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           +python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       +lua               -ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
-dnd               +mouse             -sound             +xfontset
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -fPIC -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc -std=gnu99   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm   -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib64/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently! There is an issue with compiling with Python3 because the expected name is different from the one in `/usr/bin` so symlinking `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3.6` resolved this for me:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```